Correcting projection QGIS
I wanted to create a quick flood analysis map but I try adding the DTM and DSM layers to the project but they do not align with the building layers. I've tried having the layers to have the same CRS but still does not work.
Can you explain to me how to have my layers be on top of each other?

Could you share a screenshot by exactly what you mean by 'do not align' - are they just a few metres out? KM out?

You might indicate how you "tried having the layers to have the same CRS".  Did you assign a new CRS or did you reproject/warp the layers to a new CRS?

Have each layer the correct CRS assigned? What is the CRS of each layer? What is the extent of each layer? What QGIS version are you using, precisely?
